# Link2SD Mount Script Error. [4]: can't create /system/etc/init.d/11link2sd: > Not a directory

Tags: internal-storage, external-sd, init.d

I want to move some of my apps from my internal memory to my extsdcard. I followed [this](http://www.howtogeek.com/114667/how-to-install-android-apps-to-the-sd-card-by-default-move-almost-any-app-to-the-sd-card/) to do so(I'm not using Marsh Mellow so skip the first part of the guide). When I installed Link2SD and rebooted my device it flashed an error saying:

> "Mount Script Error. [4]: can't create /system/etc/init.d/11link2sd:
>   Not a directory"

I searched for this error and landed on [this page](http://forum.xda-developers.com/general/help/link2sd-mount-script-error-4-create-t3182537). The solutions provided here do not seem to work for me and I wonder if it'd be dangerous to manually delete the file "init.d" and create the directory that Link2SD has been trying to create. But before I do so **I want to know what exactly is this file for and would it be safe to delete it**?

Bonus Question: Even if I delete it, would it be created again after I reboot my device?

Comment: The **init.d** is not a file, but a directory. What **Link2SD** is trying to do, is to write a script in that folder, since any script that's stored in said location will be automatically executed at boot (if your kernel supports the feature, that is).

Comment: @DeathMaskSalesman : But I did see the file myself. Anyway I solved the problem. I'll write an answer to it.

Answer (score 0):

Link2SD couldn't create folder "init.d" in `/system/etc` because there existed a file with the same name. I deleted the file manually by browsing to the location, launched `Link2SD` and selected the "Recreate mount script" option. It worked for me. I feared that something might go wrong with the device when I'd reboot it but everything is fine.